# THREE.js - moving object relative to screen with rotated/scaled parent(s)

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

In THREE.js, I'm trying to move objects around on screen based on mouse position. After looking at some [examples](http://jabtunes.com/labs/3d/spline3editor.html), it seemed pretty strait forward. Here's some code I borrowed from one of the examples that's mostly working for what I need:

```
function mouseMove(e){
    mouse2D.x = ( (e.pageX-canvas.offsetParent.offsetLeft) / canvas.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse2D.y = - ( (e.pageY-canvas.offsetParent.offsetTop) / canvas.clientHeight ) * 2 + 1;

    if (selected) {
      var ray = projector.pickingRay(mouse2D, PGL._camera).ray;
      var targetPos = ray.direction.clone().addSelf(ray.origin);
      targetPos.subSelf(_offset);

      obj.position.x = initPos.x + targetPos.x;
      obj.position.y = initPos.y + targetPos.y;
    }
  }
```

This works fine for moving immediate children within the scene. The problem is trying to move an object that has parent(s) that are rotated and/or scaled. How would you deal with that? Apply the objects `matrixRotationWorld` to the movement maybe?
I'm still trying to wrap my head around this stuff. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

See these examples, they can help you :

http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/misc_controls_fly.html

or

http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_interactive_voxelpainter.html